# informatica powercenter sql server connection issue

Tags: informatica-powercenter

Background: I am really new. Informatica Developer for PowerCenter Express Version: 9.6.1 HotFix 2

I am trying to connect to a sql server 2012 database. I created this connection 
, basically just changed the server, database in connection string of meatadata access and data access. I have tested I can use the user name password to access the sql server in sql server management studio. And when I click test it reports successful.
[image]

But when I create a mapping and a physical object (read) based on that connection, when I try data view on that object, it reports this error:

```
    [LDTMCMN_0029] message [com.informatica.sdk.dtm.ExecutionException: [LDTM_0072] RR_4036 Error connecting to database [
    Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0:    Login timeout expired
    SQL State: HYT00    Native Error: 0

    Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0:    A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.
    SQL State: 08001    Native Error: 87

    Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0:    SQL Server Network Interfaces: Connection string is not valid [87]. 
    SQL State: 08001    Native Error: 87
    State: 1    Severity: 16
    SQL Server Message: SQL Server Network Interfaces: Connection string is not valid [87]. 


    Database driver error...
    Function Name : Connect
    Database Error: Failed to connect to database using user [bcsgetl] and connection string [192.168.100.88:1433].].]
```

One thing to note, when I created that physical object, I used that connection and I was able to select a table, which proves the connection is successful.

Answer (score 0):

As from the error message "Connection string is not valid".

For a Native SQL Server connection work without provide it

Your can try a connection with the ODBC protocol, but instead as for the PowerCenter, where it need to be created a ODBC 64 bit connection on the Windows Server 2012, for the developer and PowerCenter Express, instead I found that it need still an ODBC but from the local machine.

Follow this steps:

-Launch the ODBC Administrator using the odbcad32.exe file located in the

C:\Windows\SysWOW64 directory.

-Create a new ODBC SQL data source under user and make sure do not use space in   the name.

-Restart the Developer Client.

-Create in the Developer Client a ODBC connection with your parameters.

Please make sure to use as "Connection String" the same you used for the ODBC       source on your local machine.

So if you called it "SQL_Local" that is your Connection String

Comment: Instead of a long answer, you should have to put a single comment with your suggestion...

Comment: I did not comment because I am not allowed. I put the word "suggestion" but actually I posted what worked for me, not simply a suggestion